# How to use ssh in a function(bash)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, variable, function

I am trying to execute few commands in a server by logging in using `sshpass` command like below.

```
SSH_ARGS='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -q'
sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP 'sudo sed -i "/^server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org/ { N; s/^server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org\n/server xxx.xx.xx.xx iburst\n&/ }" /etc/ntp.conf'
sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP 'sudo sed -i "/^#server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst/ { N; s/^#server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst\n/server xxx.xx.xx.xx iburst\n&/ }" /etc/ntp.conf'
echo "File /etc/ntp.conf is now edited"
sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP 'sudo cat /etc/ntp.conf | grep "server xxx.xx.xx.xx iburst"'
if [ $? = 0 ];
then
sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP 'sudo service ntpd status;sudo service ntpd restart'
else
echo "File /etc/ntp.conf is not updated in IP"
fi
```

So **instead of repeating sshpass everytime**, I would like to put `sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP` as a variable or function. How to do that?

I have tried ::

```
SSH_ARGS='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -q'
sshpp=`sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP` 
$sshpp 'sudo service ntpd status'
```

and this ::

```
SSH_ARGS='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -q'
sshpp() {
sshpass -p 'password' ssh ${SSH_ARGS} user@IP` 
}
sshpp 'sudo service ntpd status'
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107893/4164298) also, but not working.

How will I achieve this instead of repeating `sshpass` every time?

Comment: Why don't you put that in a script on the remote server where it needs to run?

Comment: Note that putting a password in the command line is very insecure as command lines are logged in different places and can be seen by other users with `w`.

Comment: I have multiple servers that need to make changes; using `for` loop now. If I get a solution for this, my script will look less messy and have not to repeat `ssh` everytime.

Comment: I am aware about password issue, the servers are not publicly accessible.

Comment: Your first try would work if you used doublequotes `"` for sshpp not backquotes `\``. Your second would work if you had the function use its arguments while preserving their quoting with `"$@"`. But `alias` as per answer is better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is an `alias`:

```
alias sp='sshpass -p "password" ssh $SSH_ARGS user@IP'
```

You can therefore run your commands like:

```
sp 'sudo sed -i "/^server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org/ { N; s/^server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org\n/server xxx.xx.xx.xx iburst\n&/ }" /etc/ntp.conf'
```

Note that there may be ways to simplify your life a bit more by making scripts to do these repetitive tasks, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Aliases don't take arguments; instead they _always_ append the rest of the command line after substituting the first word. Shell _functions_ and scripts do use `$*`.and `$1 ${3/foo/bar}` etc

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I updated it.